# VBA calling CSV Files

Tags: excel, vba, scripting

Here is my scenario. I have a script that runs on a server that exports used space, free space, etc to a csv file.
I have a master excel.xlsm that calls data from those csv files. But they are external links so it continues to pop up asking to update those links but the files are closed. I have tried several varations of the displayalerts = false, etc. But nothing has worked. Here is my macro that runs everything:

```
Private Sub Auto_Open()

    'MsgBox "This Excel Document will open and then close source files to update data."
    'Opens the Source CSV files so the Main Spreadsheet can update its external values.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Workbooks.Open "\\Engineering\CADD Admin\EngineeringDriveSpace\CSV_Docs\DiskReportFDrive.csv"
    Workbooks.Open "\\Engineering\CADD Admin\EngineeringDriveSpace\CSV_Docs\DiskReportGDrive.csv"
    Workbooks.Open "\\Engineering\CADD Admin\EngineeringDriveSpace\CSV_Docs\DiskReportHDrive.csv"
    Workbooks.Open "\\Engineering\CADD Admin\EngineeringDriveSpace\CSV_Docs\DiskReportJDrive.csv"
    Workbooks.Open "\\Engineering\CADD Admin\EngineeringDriveSpace\CSV_Docs\DiskReportKDrive.csv"

    'Makes the Main Spreadsheet Active
    'Activate Worksheet
    'Workbooks("EngineeringDriveSpace.xlsm").Activate
    Workbooks.Open "c:\users\nicholas.henry\Downloads\EngineeringDriveSpace.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksAlways
    'Worksheets("MH07_F").Activate
    'Sheets("MH07_F").Select

    'Pause Application For Testing
    'Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#

    'Closes the Source CSV files.

    Workbooks("DiskReportFDrive.csv").Close SaveChanges:=False
    Workbooks("DiskReportGDrive.csv").Close SaveChanges:=False
    Workbooks("DiskReportHDrive.csv").Close SaveChanges:=False
    Workbooks("DiskReportJDrive.csv").Close SaveChanges:=False
    Workbooks("DiskReportKDrive.csv").Close SaveChanges:=False


End Sub
```

Basically im looking for ZERO intervention from the end person opening the link (manager) even though he is tech savvy. What the idea situation would be is, he opens the master spread sheet, it opens all the other CSV files, updates the data, then closes the CSV files and leaves the master sheet open and on top WITHOUT warning him "we cant update some of the links in your workbook right now"

Comment: I assume the links that can't be updated are within `EngineeringDriveSpace.xlsm` - have you checked to see which ones it can't update?  (You possibly have links to files you haven't loaded or, more likely, which don't exist.)

Comment: Why don't you keep the object references for the books you open, instead of discarding them and then fetching them back from the `Workbooks` collection? `Set FDriveBook = Workbooks.Open(...)` ...

Comment: YowE3k: Space A2 llooks like is this: 
=IF(DiskReportKDrive.csv!$A2, DiskReportKDrive.csv!$A2, "")
They are being read from each drive's individual CSV file. Most of the VBA works, so it opens the csv files (which in turn updates the links and the master spreadsheet updates) then closes the csv files, but then the master spreadsheet says it cant update the links because the csv files are closed. If they are all open at the same time all the references update automatically. But i dont want the end user to have to open 6 excel documents to only look at the master one anyways.

Comment: So I assume you've tried `Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False` ? I would say go place that and `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` in the CSV files, but it looks like you've got them as CSV files for a reason.

Comment: I hadnt tried that one, but it still seems to say "we cant update some of the links in your workbook right now, you can continue without updating their values, or edit the links you think are wrong." Then when i click edit links it shows each sheet that has a reference to each individual csv file. Only reason why they are csv files is because my script that queries each of the servers drives (5 in total) writes its used space/free space to it's own csv file.